How to connect running Airflow server to VS Code?
I am using Elestio cloud provider and it spun up Airflow server for me. I installed the Airflow official VS Code extension.
When trying to add server it asks for both server URL, username and password.
However my cloud provider only provides two items of credential:

In VS Code:


ask for the username of your provider.
probably there is a default username or your account could be your username
